# Huge request duration value for a particular php script

Tags: php, php-fpm

We are facing issues with a php-fpm server that spawns too many children. This morning, I set up [php-fpm's status page](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page/), and got an interesting piece of information : among all the scripts that are executed by the the children, one has a request duration that amounts to `3050111212255` µs which equals roughly to 35 days, which is the uptime of the machine, although we restart `php-fpm` recently. Here the output of the status page for this script.

```
pid:                  19998
state:                Idle
start time:           29/Aug/2014:14:48:25 +0200
start since:          578
requests:             244
request duration:     3050444744915
request method:       POST
request URI:          /app.php?_format=json
content length:       96
user:                 jobuser
script:               /home/frontoffice/instances/encoding/current/web/app.php
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  7864320
```

Do you think this is a bug in php-fpm ?

Comment: I am facing the same weird problem too, did you find the reason?

Comment: sadly, I did not.

Comment: The weird thing is "request duration" > "start since" ^^

Comment: Yeah, it makes no sense :P

Comment: If people would stop abandoning their questions and actually post the solutions when they find them it would sure be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like an old bug not resolved yet:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62382

Answer (score 0):

People who have same problem can try to add
**request_terminate_timeout = 300**
to their php-fpm pool configuration

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to add this to my config and see what I get. However, I think the problem is deeper. There must be an underlying reason why these processes are misbehaving. I have a few posts that are related and when I figure them out this thread is one that I will be updating. Thanks again.